# asp mvc ajax call - json parameter received as null

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I call a mvc controller using ajax using :

```
 var ajaxOptions = { url: url, type: 'POST', contentType: 'application/json', 
                     data: JSON.stringify(data) };
```

I send the following JSON in data

```
data = "{"TagList":["AA","BB","CCC","DDDD"]}"
```

In my controller the following method is called

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Update(TagItem tagItem)
```

and I get TagItem.TagList = null

```
public class TagItem
{
    public List<string> TagList { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `tagItem` wrapper in JSON.

```
data = {"tagItem":{"TagList":["AA","BB","CCC","DDDD"]}};

var ajaxOptions = 
             { url: url, 
               type: 'POST', 
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
               data: JSON.stringify(data) 
              };
```

Try this for instance:-

```
  var data = { "tagItem": { "TagList": ["AA", "BB", "CCC", "DDDD"]} };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "home/test",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this with `contentType`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

**Added:**

As @PSL found OP lost `tagItem`, after wrapping current `data` with it, code must work.

Comment: Looking at his issue it seems more like he is missing the wrapper.